# Remove MacOS partition from macbook pro retina dualboot with ubuntu mate 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, macbook, refind

I would like to remove the MacOS partition from my macbook pro retina since I'm not using it more.
I know how to remove a partition using gparted, but I'm using refind, installed through MacOS, as bootloader. I'm not sure if I can reboot after deleting MacOS.

This is the output of boot-info, maybe can be usefull.

http://paste2.org/91XWkKGG

Answer (score 0):

It looks like rEFInd is installed on your EFI System Partition (ESP), so deleting the OS X partition should not affect its operation. That said, it also looks as if the system is configured to boot through GRUB, not through rEFInd. Maybe that's deceptive (Macs can be weird in how they boot), though.

To add to your safety before deleting the OS X partition, you can download a CD-R or USB flash drive version of rEFInd from [its downloads page,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) prepare a boot medium, and test it before you proceed. That way, if booting goes wonky, you should still be able to use rEFInd on the external medium to boot into Ubuntu on a temporary basis, and with any luck correct the problem.